# Choosing till or before

Tags: prepositions

In an exercise I am to fill blanks with suitable prepositions

> He does not leave his house ________ 9 o'clock.

Answer according to my book is **before** but I think I can also use **till** without any change in meaning.

Another sentence was

> I must start ________ dawn to reach the station in time.

Answer according to book is **at** but dawn refers to a period of time how can one use **at** here. I think it should be **before dawn**

Comment: In the first sentence, you could use *before* or *till* but they don't mean quite the same. With till there is a stronger implication that he leaves at 9 (and not 10, 11 etc). In the second sentence, you can use *at* or *before* - dawn can be treated as a point in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He does not leave his house **until** 9 o'clock.

This **strongly** implies that he does leave his house, and that he does so at "exactly" 9 o'clock (a reasonable amount of imprecision is allowed of course).

> He does not leave his house **before** 9 o'clock.

This only **weakly** suggests that he does in fact leave his house. He may or may not. More importantly, it only asserts that if he does, he doesn't do it before 9 o'clock. He may do it at 9 o'clock **or anytime after**.

---

> I must start **at** dawn to reach the station in time.

Your belief that [**dawn**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn) is a period of time rather than a specific moment is incorrect:

> **Dawn** ... is the time that marks the beginning of twilight before sunrise. It is recognized by the appearance of indirect sunlight being scattered in the atmosphere, when the centre of the Sun's disc reaches 18° below the horizon.

Since it is a specific moment, **at** fits. (Here too, a reasonable amount of imprecision is assumed. It's unlikely the author will consult astronomical tables to calculate the exact time of dawn at that position on that day. Colloquially, "at dawn" means "whenever I notice the sun starting to come up.)

You may have been confusing dawn with **[twilight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twilight)**.

Comment: I interpret that first one slightly differently; I'd say: _He does not leave his house until 9 o'clock_ implies that he never leaves his house before 9 (although he may depart later than 9).

Comment: @J.R.  I think the point is that "until" implies the strong possibility that, after 9, he **will** leave his house.  Meanwhile "before" suggests a habit of not leaving until after that time, and we don't know if he will or won't leave.   I think this is reasonable, although it probably depends greatly on context.

Comment: @Andrew - Agreed. My point was that I don't take "until" to mean "exactly at" in this context.